# How to display returned json string in a table through Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am developing an application that needs to show the data returned in JSON format in a HTML table. My following code is capable of retrieving JSON data.

```
function bincontroller($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.updateModel = function () {
        $http({
            url: "/abc/abc/ss/ds/",
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                data: {
                    "markingPeriod": 8,
                    "syear": 2013,
                    "teacherId": "",
                    "startDate": "2013-11-25",
                    "endDate": "2013-12-26"
                },
                r: "api/v1/Attendance/Bin"
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
            angular.forEach(data.collection.response, function (value, index) {
                angular.forEach(value, function (val, ky) {
                    console.log(ky + " : " + val);
                });
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: your edit is invalid, it decreases readability, so I've reverted it. Don't ever vandalize posts like this.

Comment: thanks @MaxMommersteeg ... i was in a hurry for getting the answer. and mistyped it

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, didn't notice my edit was set in queue, but it was way better than post at begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angularTable](http://angulartable.com/) and pass your JSON as the angularTable `model` via the `$scope`.